# Bash command for automatically confirm option during installation

Tags: bash, installation

Whenever you're installing a package, it usually prompts for y/n confirmation, is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on debian based distros you can run:

```
apt-get -y install <package_to_install>
```

to further automate it (in case of installing packages that asks some questions - for example mysql-server asks for db root password) run:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install <package_to_install>
```

Answer (score 4):

You might try

```
yes | install-package.sh
```

Comment: awesome! thanks, I didn't think of this. But I have one slight issue. What if I'm trying to install several packages? sudo apt-get install xxx yyy zzz. Do I have to pipe 3 yes to it? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @izomorphius I was wondering if there was a better way to do this other than having 3 pipes

Comment: @Shelby.S: Try it yourself. One pipe is enough.

Comment: @choroba ,Shelby that is exactly what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Try the -f switch. It probably depends on which package manager you have, so you should check the man-page for your package manager to confirm.

Comment: indeed, apt-get has -f switch but it's man page considers it dangerous so I would stick with -y